# keyNotFound decodable error while parsing a JSON object

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

```
Function call:

func getdata() {
        
        let baseURL = “my url“
        let token = “my token”
        
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL)!)
        urlRequest.addValue("bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        let task = URLSession.shared
        task.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
            
            
            if (error == nil && data != nil && data?.count != 0) {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data!)
                    print(result.result.workStreams.workGroupObjects)
                } catch let error {
                    debugPrint("error occurred while decoding: \(error)")
                } 
            } else {
        return 
            }                                   
        }.resume()
        
    }
```

> error in the console :   "error occured while decoding:
> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil),
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
> value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"result\",
> intValue: nil) (\"result\").", underlyingError: nil))"

```
Models: 

// MARK: - Root
struct Root: Decodable {
    let result: Result
    let status: Status
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Decodable {
//    let reportList: [Any?]
    let userLayOut: String
    let workStreams: WorkStreams
}

// MARK: - WorkStreams
struct WorkStreams: Decodable {
    let workGroupObjects: String
//    let ownerWorkGroupList: [Any?]
}

// MARK: - Status
struct Status: Decodable {
    let number: Int
//    let message: NSNull
}
```

am i missing something in my models? if yes what is it??

```
JSON: 

{
    "result": {
        "ReportList": [],
        "UserLayOut": “ This is a string ”,
        "workStreams": {
            "workGroupObjects": “ This is also a string ”,
            "OwnerWorkGroupList": []
        }
    },
    "Status": {
        "Number": 0,
        "Message": null
    }
}
```

can someone please explain me what should i am i doing wrong?

Comment: Right before the JSONDecoder line insert `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))` and compare it with the JSON you posted. And consolidate the spelling. A lot of uppercase keys don’t match the lowercase properties. And the `data > 0`check is pointless. If `data` is empty you will get an error anyway.

Comment: That json doesn't generate the posted error message so maybe you are receiving something else. Apart from that you will need to add `CodingKey` enums to your structs to map attribute names against property names

Comment: thank you @vadian i tried the             print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)) and the error i get is Optional("{\"Message\":\"Authorization has been denied for this request.\"}"), how ever the same works in postman!! and i do get data in bytes which is Optional(61 bytes)

Comment: That's a server error and the error message is exactly 61 bytes long.

Comment: thanks you so much for this answer, you have been very helpful as always!!